# Are all smooth submanifolds locally flat?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

I was doing Exercise 8.3 from the book *From Calculus to Cohomology*, Ib H. Madsen,

> Suppose that $M \subset \mathbb{R}^k$ (with the induced topology from $\mathbb{R}^k$) is an $n$-dimensional topological manifolds. Include $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k+n}$. Show that $M$ is locally flat in $\mathbb{R}^{k+n}$.

What is the purpose of including $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k+n}$, when M is already an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Is it generally true that a smooth submanifold is always a locally flat submanifold? I find that the following definition of smooth submanifold in the book seems to coincide with the definition of [local flatness on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_flatness).

> A subset $N \subset M^n$ of a smooth manifold is said to be a smooth submanifold if the following condition is satisfied: for every $x \in N$ there exists a chart $h: U\rightarrow U'$ on $M$ such that $x \in U$ and $h(U \cap N)=U'\cap \mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: What is the definition of locally flat for topological manifolds? And should it be true for all $n>0$?

Comment: @PaulFrost Local Flatness had not been introduced in the book. And no, it specified that $n$ be the dimension of $M$. The only idea I have is that $M$ is locally a graph in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ if inclusion is done correctly.

Comment: For local flatness of topological submanifolds in the case $n=1, k=3$ see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426501/why-are-all-knots-trivial-in-4d/4008370#4008370). I think similar arguments work in general. And smooth submanifolds are always locally flat. It is a good exercise in understanding the definition of a smooth submanifold and the constant rank theorem (depending on your definition of a smooth submanifold).

Comment: The concept of a *locally flat topological submanifold* is a bit hidden in the text. It is introduced before Theorem 8.14: "It is defined in analogy to Definition 8.8, but with a homeomorphism instead of the diffeomorphism $h$. "

This is exactly the Wikipedia definition of [local flatness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_flatness). Therefore a smooth submanifold of a smooth manifold is a locally flat submanifold **by definition**.

Comment: @PaulFrost To sum it up, not all topological submanifolds are locally flat, but every smooth submanifold is locally flat, due to the constant rank theorem. Am I correct?

Comment: @JeffreyMak Yes, each smooth submanifold is locally flat. But this has nothing to do with the constant rank theorem, it is the **definition** of a smooth submanifold. Okay, there are alternative definitions of smooth submanifolds (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3828888)), and local flatness would be a theorem then. The [Alexander horned sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere) is an example of a topological manifold $M \subset \mathbb R^3$ which is not locally flat.